# Eslint: use airbnb styles but exclude all jsx-a11y

Tags: eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I would like to use airbnb styles ESLint.
However, accessibility does not bring values in my project, and actually it add more noise to the code.

Is there a way to use AirBnb eslint but disable `jsx-a11y`?
I can fork the AirBnb repo and delete the link, but just wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 9):

In your `.eslintrc` you can change:

```
"extends": [
  "airbnb"
]
```

to

```
"extends": [
  "airbnb-base",
  "airbnb/rules/react"
]
```

All credit goes to [oustn](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/1665#issuecomment-466318869)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Typescript, then change:

```
"extends": [
  "airbnb-typescript"
],
```

To:

```
"extends": [
  "eslint-config-airbnb-base",
  "airbnb/rules/react"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall `eslint-config-airbnb`, then install and use `eslint-config-airbnb-base`, `eslint-plugin-react`, and `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`. If you also want TypeScript, install `eslint-config-airbnb-typescript` as normal. Your eslint config should have changed from:

```
extends: [
  'airbnb',
  'airbnb-typescript'
]
```

to:

```
extends: [
  'eslint:recommended',
  'plugin:react/recommended',
  'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
  'airbnb-base',
  'airbnb-typescript'
]
```